# Firebase runTransactionBlock not working in swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, swift3

After updating the Xcode 8 and convert the Swift 2 project into Swift 3, other codes work well, but `runTransactionBlock` is not working and found this error:

> "runTransactionBlock: usage detected while persistence is enabled. Please be aware that transactions *will not* be persisted across app restarts"

What could be wrong?

Firebase runTransaction Code

```
postRef.runTransactionBlock({ (currentData: FIRMutableData) -> FIRTransactionResult in
            if var post = currentData.value as? [String : AnyObject], let uid = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid {
                var stars : Dictionary<String, Bool>
                stars = post["likeMap"] as? [String : Bool] ?? [:]
                var likeCount = post["likeCount"] as? Int ?? 0
                if let _ = stars[uid] {
                    // Unstar the post and remove self from stars
                    likeCount -= 1
                    self._liked = false
                    stars.removeValue(forKey: uid)
                } else {
                    // Star the post and add self to stars
                    likeCount += 1
                    self._liked = true
                    stars[uid] = true
                }
                post["likeCount"] = likeCount as AnyObject?
                post["likeMap"] = stars as AnyObject?
                self._likeCount = likeCount
                // Set value and report transaction success
                currentData.value = post

                return FIRTransactionResult.success(withValue: currentData)
            }
            return FIRTransactionResult.success(withValue: currentData)
        }) { (error, committed, snapshot) in
            if let error = error {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 7):

Not sure which version of Firebase SDK you are using but I will provide you a basic example I used **runTransactionBlock** successfully:

## Database

[image]

---

## Code

```
let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
let refReservations = ref.child("reservations")


refReservations.runTransactionBlock { (currentData: FIRMutableData) -> FIRTransactionResult in
  if var data = currentData.value as? [String: Any] {
    var count = data["count"] as? Int ?? 0
    count += 1
    data["count"] = count
    
    currentData.value = data
  }
  
  return FIRTransactionResult.success(withValue: currentData)
}
```

---

## Note

I've used Firebase SDK version : **3.0.1** and you can get this info from your code using this method: `FIRDatabase.sdkVersion()`

Comment: My firebase SDK Version is also 3.0.1

Comment: Good answer, clean and straight to the point. One thing though, **FIRTransactionResultsuccess(withValue: currentData)** has been renamed to: **TransactionResult.success(withValue: currentData)**

Answer (score 2):

That message is a warning that your app is using transactions *and* is persisting data to disk.

When you enable disk persistence, the (recent) data that your app observes is persisted to disk. That way the data will be available in case the user restarts the app at a moment when there is no network connection.

In this *disconnected* state, the Firebase client will also store all local write operations to disk in a so-called *pending writes queue*. Then, when a network connection becomes available again, the Firebase client will send all pending writes to the server, and of course also receive any updates that the server has for it.

But, while disconnected, the Firebase client will *not* persist transactions to disk. Since that combination may not be what you expected, Firebase logs the warning about it that you see.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I found the explanation and the solution.

The example from the Firebase documentation is wrong for Swift 3 because it says that the FIRMutableData object that comes from the database is of type [String:AnyObject], when instead it should be [String: Any].

The reason is that the response is actually [String:Dictionary] and Dictionary is not AnyObject(Any can represent an instance of any type at all, including function types and optional types.
AnyObject can represent an instance of any class type.) because Dictionary is not a class.

In order for that code to work you must replace this line of code:

```
if var post = currentData.value as? [String : AnyObject], let uid = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid {
```

with this line:

```
if var post = currentData.value as? [String : Any], let uid = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid {
```